# image is not being added on the canvas through socket.io?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, react-konva, konva

Hi im building a collaborative whiteboard app with Konva. I want to drag images on the canvas and also make it displayed to the other clients connected to the app. I've tried to do some things but its not really working..
Here is what im trying to do:

```
{loadImages.map(image => (
  <img id="img" className="img"
  src={image.picture}
  width="200"
  height="200"
  onDragStart={(e) => {
    dragUrl.current = e.target.src;}}
/>
))}
    
    <div
        onDrop={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          // register event position
          stageEl.current.setPointersPositions(e);
          // add image
          setImages(
            images.concat([
              {
                ...stageEl.current.getPointerPosition(),
                src: dragUrl.current,
              },
            ])
          );
          socket.emit("canvas-data", [
            {
              ...stageEl.current.getPointerPosition(),
              src: dragUrl.current,
            },
          ])
        }}
        onDragOver={(e) => 
          e.preventDefault()
        }
      >
```

When the image gets dropped the image data is emitted to the socket server. An example of the image data would be this:

```
[ { x: 457.90001572844375,
   y: 126.92498779296875,
   src: 'http://localhost:3000/images/kitten.jpg' } ]
```

Then the image data gets received here:

```
socket.on("canvas-data", function(data){
      var interval = setInterval(function(){
        clearInterval(interval);
       
        var stageData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
        console.log(stageData[0].x);
        var layer = new Konva.Layer();
        var image = new Konva.Image(
        {
          x: stageData[0].x,
          y: stageData[0].y,
          src: stageData[0].src
        
        })
      layer.add(image);
      stageEl.current.add(layer);
  
    
  
      })
    }, 200)
```

Why is the dropped image still not being shown on other clients?

Answer (score -1):

`Konva.Image` doesn't have `src` attirbute. In order to show image on canvas you need to load it first.

Take a look into [Konva Image Tutorial](https://konvajs.org/docs/shapes/Image.html) or [react-konva Image](https://konvajs.org/docs/react/Images.html)